# how to do a facebook like to a given postId from my android app?

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm writing an android app and I would like to offer the user to do a "fb like"

to some given facebook pages/images/post

how can I do this?

I have tried using plain Http Post, but it returns all kind of errors.

So I think using Graph API will be neater. no?

```
public class LikeFbPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        ImageButton mLockImage;
        Response fbServerResponse;

        public LikeFbPostAsyncTask(ImageButton lockImage) {
            mLockImage = lockImage;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i("LikeFbPostAsyncTask", "Starting web task...");
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... fbPostId) {

            Request likeRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(),
                    fbPostId[0] + "/likes", null, HttpMethod.POST,
                    new Request.Callback() {

                        // here is non-ui thread
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(final Response response) {
                            Log.i(TAG, response.toString());
                            fbServerResponse = response;

                        }
                    });
            Request.executeBatchAndWait(likeRequest);
            return null;
        }
```

In addition I'm not sure I'm using a proper "post id".

I haven't seen a good example outside nor in the official documentation.

Comment: You don't have to use `AsyncTask` if you're using a `Request.Callback`. Once you make `likeRequest` just call `likeRequest.executeAsync()`.

Comment: can you show me from scratch how to do a fb like?

Comment: but i get `errorMessage: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`